# Why does my function tell me that I have a Type Mismatch?

Tags: function, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to get the following function to work:

```
Private Function FirstOfMonth(MonthsAgo As Integer) As Date
  FirstOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now() - MonthsAgo), 1)
End Function
```

I'm passing in a value as follows:

```
FirstOfMonth(4)
```

The aim of the function is to return the date for the first of the month a number of 'MonthsAgo'.

However, whenever I run it it tells me that I have a Type Mismatch.

I'm new to programming, so if there's anyone that can point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong, I'd be very grateful.  It's slowing me down solving a fairly simple problem.

Comment: `now() - 4` is most likely not what you want to be using to determine a month.

Comment: It doesn't throw errors for me. Where exactly does it say the mismatch is?

Comment: The reason you are having problems is also the parentheses: `FirstOfMonth 4`  Do not use parentheses unless you are assigning to a variable `dte=FirstOfMonth(4)` or using Call.

Comment: Do you always pass a value (4) or do you use a variable? If you use a variable, it must be an integer as per your code: `Dim monthsAgo As Integer`, `MonthsAgo=4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you meant to be doing was:

```
' Note the brackets change around 'Month(Now()) - MonthsAgo'
FirstOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()) - MonthsAgo, 1)
```

However, even this won't work. Consider the case where the month is January (1). In that scenario you will end up with a Date of `2012/-3/1` which is obviously complete nonsense!

You will instead need to use the [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb7z8yf9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function:

```
DateAdd("m", 4, Now())
```

So your entire function looks like

```
Private Function FirstOfMonth(MonthsAgo As Integer) As Date
    Dim newDate
    newDate = DateAdd("m", 0 - MonthsAgo , Now())
    FirstOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(newDate), Month(newDate), 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, Now() is a double. `Now()-4 = 27/10/2012 14:41:28` the number is subtracted from days, so Now() or Date() - *n* is the number of days ago.

Comment: @Remou Strictly, all Dates in VBScript are doubles, as per the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.84).aspx). They represent the number of days since `1/1/1899` (I think), so subtracting from this value will have that effect.

Comment: @Remou I can't see a note from you about passing without parantheses. As I remember (been a while since I've done any VBScript thank God!), you use parantheses if you are calling a `Function` and don't use parantheses when calling a `Sub` - is that right?

Comment: @Remou Agreed - I'd already removed the first sentence from my answer :)

Comment: This is VBA, not VBScript. The note is on the OP.

Comment: Ah, yes - it does say that doesn't it! Well, I'll leave my answer here as I've given the correct logic he needs. Maybe someone else can post the correct syntax if I've made any mistakes :)

Comment: I think that's just about cracked it RB.  Thanks for your and Remou's help!

Answer (score 0):

You must pass FirstOfMonth(4) into a "Date" variable